# sbt server fails to start throwing error 231

Tags: scala, sbt

When I am trying to start sbt, it fails throwing an IO exception.

Version of SBT - `1.1.2`

Version of Scala - `2.12.6`

Error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\projectname\project
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to example (in build file:/C:/Users/username/IdeaProjects/projectname/)
[error] server failed to start on local:sbt-server-ad238fc8ee352b69065c. java.io.IOException: Could not create lock for
\\.\pipe\sbt-server-ad238fc8ee352b69065c_lock, error 231
```

Comment: (there have been lots of bugfixes made to sbt since 1.1.2, upgrading to 1.2.3 would probably be a good idea)

Comment: Restarting intellij fixed this for me.

Comment: If you've opened an sbt shell in IntelliJ, that sbt shell may be holding the lock. Try closing the IntelliJ sbt shell by entering exit into the shell.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Analysing the [source](https://github.com/sbt/ipcsocket/blob/609cf3dc723296b6f98619540903693c54cb0d37/src/main/java/org/scalasbt/ipcsocket/Win32NamedPipeServerSocket.java#L104) of the throw it seems error code [`231`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes--0-499-#ERROR_PIPE_BUSY) refers to Windows error:

```
ERROR_PIPE_BUSY

231 (0xE7)

All pipe instances are busy.
```

The pipe cannot be accessed because another process is using it, so try closing down IntelliJ and any other SBT server running, and try again later. Perhaps even reboot the machine, and then start a single system SBT server (not IntelliJ), and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks Mario. Had IntelliJ running. Once I stopped it - the sbt-server starts fine. Many thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: In my case, it was another open sbt